# moving a rectangle to a specific point

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to move a rectangle to a specific point with a specific speed.

however it only works properly if `x,y` (the point i am trying to move it to) are the same. otherwise, if `x` was bigger than `y` it would move at a 45 degree angle until `self.location[1]==y`(it reached where it needed to be for `y`), then it would move in a straight for `x`  and vise versa.

i know that  i would have to change `speed_y` so that it was slower. how do i work out what speed i need y to be at in order to get the rectangle to move to `location` in a straight line no matter what `location` is?

full function:

```
def move(self,x,y,speed):
    if speed==0:
        self.location=[x,y]
    else:
        speed_x = speed
        speed_y = speed
        if x > 0 and not self.location[0]==x: # x is positive and not already where it needs to be
            if not x == y:
                speed_x = something # need to slow down the speed so that it gets to  y as the same time as it gets to x

            self.speed_x=speed_x
        else: self.speed_x=0

        if y > 0 and not self.location[1]==y: # same for y
            if not x == y:
                speed_y = something # need to slow down the speed so that it gets to  y as the same time as it gets to x

            self.speed_y=speed_y
        else: self.speed_y=0
```

Comment: In order to figure out `speed_x` and `speed_y`, you'll probably want to [use trigonometry](http://www.raywenderlich.com/35866/trigonometry-for-game-programming-part-1)

Comment: note that `speed_x / speed_y = x / y`. Hence, `if x>y: speed_y = speed * y / x` and vice versa. The only other condition that you will have to check for is the one where `x == 0 and y == 0`. Or preferably, `x < delta and y < delta`.

Comment: @ssm how does `speed_x / speed_y = x / y` work? i'm pretty sure that speed_x / speed_y does not = x / y. xy is where the rectangle is going to. speed_x and speed_y is the speed in the x and y direction.

Comment: @Thedudxo: if t = total time for the movement, x = speed_x * t, y = speed_y * t. x / y = (speed_x * t)/(speed_y * t) = speed_x/speed_y. Not sure how you are *pretty sure* that that the equality doesn't hold. This is middle school physics.

Comment: Assumption: initial position = 0,0. Otherwise, just do an axis transformation.

Comment: @ssm i haven't done physics. its not avalible to me yet. you never mentioned t on your first comment.

Comment: @Thedudxo: Ok, my bad. In your case, `speed_x / speed_y = (x - self.location[0]) / (y - self.location[1])`. That's the axis transformation I was talking about. I think most of the other answers (eg. Rosso) do the same thing. Just remember that you don't divide by zero (or a very small number) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your speeds to a ratio of required distance for each axis.
e.g. if distance to x is half distance to y then speed_x should be half speed_y.

Further example as requested:

```
distance_x = x-self.location[0]
distance_y = y-self.location[1]
if abs(distance_x) < abs(distance_y):
    ratio = distance_x/abs(distance_y)
    speed_x = ratio * speed
```

edit: Reworked the directions of example.

Comment: example of how to do this please? i tried it and probably did it wrong. the rectangle started moving all over the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what you are asking for, but see if this helps you:

```
speed_x = speed*(cos(atan2((y-self.location[1]), (x-self.location[0])))) 
speed_y = speed*(sin(atan2((y-self.location[1]), (x-self.location[0]))))
```

That would "slow" the speed you are given by splitting it in the values needed to get to where you want your box to be at the same time.

Pardon any errors in my english/python, im not native on either one :)

Comment: what is atan2 exactly?

Comment: Its a bit weird to explain, basically, its function that returns the angle(in radians) that a line from an origin to a point would make if it crossed an horizontal line that contains the origin point. In my example i find the distance(x and y separately) between the box location and the point you are moving to and use it as the x and y coordinates "from the origin".

Comment: i assume these are part of the math module?

Answer (score -1):

You need mathematical calculations to get new position in every move.

Comment: More precisely, as Marius sad, you need trigonometry.

Comment: i dont understand how i can use trig to calculate the speed i need. i can understand using it to get the distance away from something or the angle to something. could you give me an example?

Comment: See answer MetaShinryu.